# How to "lock" records in kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a stream application that reads from a topic and stores the state in a global store. There are several processors that write to the same topic by reading from the state store, updating a particular field, and writing it back to the topic.

I've noticed that some writes contain stale data and overwrites a record that was previously updated. I want to know what techniques I can use to achieve this "locking" of the records so that no processor updates the record while it is being read and processed by another. So far I believe this can be achieved by enabling exactly-once processing but would like your expert opinion on this and pointers to other things I might be missing.

```scala
streamBuilder
  .addGlobalStore(
          Stores
            .keyValueStoreBuilder(
              productGlobalState,
              keySerde,
              valueSerde
           )
          .withLoggingDisabled(),
          "product-source-1",
          consumedInstance,
          processorSupplier
        )
       .stream("product-source-1")
       .transform(transformer1)
       .to("product-sink")
       .stream("product-source-2")
       .transform(transformer2)
       .to("product-sink")


//state store processor
val productProcessorSupplier: ProcessorSupplier[ProductId, ProductValue] =
    () =>
      new AbstractProcessor[ProductId, ProductValue] {

        private var store: KeyValueStore[ProductId, ProductValue] = _

        override def init(context: ProcessorContext): Unit = {
          super.init(context)
          this.store = context
            .getStateStore(ProductGlobalStoreName)
            .asInstanceOf[KeyValueStore[ProductId, ProductValue]]
        }

        override def process(key: ProductId, value: ProductValue): Unit = {
          store.put(key, value)
          context().commit()
        }
      }

//transformer1
val transformer1: ProductTransformer =
    () =>
      new Transformer[
        ProductId,
        ProductValue,
        KeyValue[ProductId, ProductValue]
      ] {

        private var prodStore: KeyValueStore[ProductId, ProductValue] = _

        override def init(context: ProcessorContext): Unit = {
          this.prodStore = context
            .getStateStore(ProductGlobalStoreName)
            .asInstanceOf[KeyValueStore[ProductId, ProductValue]]
        }

        override def transform(key: ProductId, value: ProductValue): KeyValue[ProductId, ProductValue] = {
          val updatedProd = Option(prodStore.get(key)).map { p =>
            value.copy(isSale = p.isSale, isNew = p.isNew)//attempt to preserve these fields and not override them
          } getOrElse value

          KeyValue.pair(key, updatedProd)
        }

        override def close(): Unit = ()
      }


//transformer2
val transformer2 = () => new Transformer[ProductId, ProductValue, KeyValue[ProductId, ProductValue]] {

        private var context: ProcessorContext = _
        protected var prodStore: KeyValueStore[ProductId, ProductValue] = _

        override def init(context: ProcessorContext): Unit = {
          this.context = context
          this.prodStore = context
            .getStateStore(ProductGlobalStoreName)
            .asInstanceOf[KeyValueStore[ProductId, ProductValue]]
        }

       override def transform(key: ProductId, value: ProductValue): KeyValue[ProductId, ProductValue] = {
          val product = prodStore.get(key)
          val newValue = product.copy(product.isNew = true)
          KeyValue.pair(key, newValue)

        }
}

//... other transformers similar to transformer2 but updating a different fields.
```

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see exactly how you're consuming and updating the records back to the topic?

Comment: Thx. Added sample code. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Why do you use global state store? A global state store will broadcast/replicate it's state and thus if you have multiple threads running they may perform redundant work. Because everything is async my nature, there is no way to "lock" a record. Maybe using a regular store that is sharded can help?

Comment: This reason is that each local chart needs to retrieve data from the global table. The global table is populated from a different topic. If I understand correctly, it is possible that the shard doesn't have the record I'm looking for. Since it belongs to a different topic, there's no guarantee the corresponding key will exist in that shard. Pls do let me know if I'm totally wrong about how that works.